# how to achieve c++ phone number format : (000)-000-000?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

std::wstring inputfield;

void function(uint32_t val)
{
    std::wstring keystring;
    keystring = std::to_wstring(val);    
    inputfield = inputfield + keystring; 
    std::wstringstream s;
    s << L"(" << inputfield << L") ";
    std::wstring str = s.str();
    std::wcout << str << "\n";
    return;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t x ;
    while(cin>>x)
    {
        function(x);
        cout<< *(&x)<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying string format to get output like (000)-000-000 or USA phonenumber format, But I am not able to achieve that, Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change string `000000000` or simillar (and you do, even if input is a number, simply convert it with `std::to_string`) then just add a few characters in proper places.

```
std::string format_number(std::string str) {
    if(str.size() != 9) {
        throw std::logic_error{"Phone number is not 9-characters long"};
    }

    str.insert(str.begin(), '(');
    str.insert(str.begin() + 4, ')');
    str.insert(str.begin() + 5, '-');
    str.insert(str.begin() + 9, '-');

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kamil

Comment: @Ravi I'd be glad if you marked this answer as correct if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate input phone numbers and then pass structures like this;

```
struct numbers {     
     int A;
     int B;
     int C;
} // then get (A)-B-C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
//---- The following function will be invoked by the thread library
void thread_proc(std::string msg)
{
    std::cout << "ThreadProc msg:" << msg;
}
int main()
{
    // creates a new thread and execute thread_proc on it.
    std::thread t(thread_proc, "Hello World\n");
    // Waiting for the thread_proc to complete its execution
    // before exiting from the program
    t.join();
}  



How to resolve this error
  $ g++ Dummy.cpp -o Dummy -std=c++1z -pthread
    Dummy.cpp: In function 'int main()':
    Dummy.cpp:12:10: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
       12 |     std::thread t(thread_proc, "Hello World\n");
          |          ^~~~~~
    Dummy.cpp:3:1: note: 'std::thread' is defined in header '<thread>'; did you forget to '#include <thread>'?
        2 | #include <thread>
      +++ |+#include <thread>
        3 | #include <string>
    Dummy.cpp:15:5: error: 't' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'tm'?
       15 |     t.join();
          |     ^
          |     tm
```